# Issues after enabling debugging of .Net Core source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, debug-symbols

I wanted to be able to step through/debug the source code of the .Net Core framework, since it is open source now and everything.

So I followed some answer on here, or something, but I've forgotten exactly what I did.
The problem is that the loading of the symbols took forever *each time I started debugging* and, worse, Visual Studio would no longer break on most exceptions and whenever there was some issue it would break but show me the exception in some esoteric class or file that I, presume, is part of .Net Core even though I know the actual exception is being thrown in my own code.

So, now I want to fix that and have the symbols loaded once and then used from the cache and VS breaking on exceptions like it should normally.

Failing that I'd like to undo whatever I did but, like I said, don't remember exactly what I did. Here's what I *think* I did:

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General` and check the following options:

- Enable .Net Framework source stepping
- Enable source server support

and unchecked:

- Require source files to exactly match the original version.

I also have both "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and "Nuget.org Symbol Servers" in my "Symbols" section and the option "Load all modules, unless excluded" selected.

So, how can I still step through .Net Core source and have VS behave like normal with exceptions and not load symbols for 5 minutes every time I start debugging

-OR-

How do I undo any options to have everything like before?

Comment: What is your memory usage?  Sound like you are on an embedded processor and running out of memory.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm on a 32 Gig RAM machine. -_-

Comment: But how much of the 32G is used by the rest of the system?  Is the 32G fragmented?

Comment: @jdweng, the system uses 64 of those 32Gigs of RAM, the memory is fragmented, defragmented and then segmented by arbitrary rules, Visual Studio has access to 8bits of said memory.

Comment: Debugging info are in a pdb file in the release folder of the project.  Make sure the date matches the exe file you use.  It should only get loaded once.